# I want to have a list of images to display randome, which is the best way?

Tags: arrays, image, list, button, setbackground

I want to have a list of images that will be displayed in the background of a button randomly every time I click it.

Which is the best way to do it? I assume that not with an array since it has same size since it's initialized, and I think that I would like to reduced the list every time I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

In js:

```js
var array = ["https://madeby.google.com/static/images/google_g_logo.svg","http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2015/12/google-amp-fast-speed-travel-ss-1920.jpg"]
//whatever links you want
function go(){
    var x = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)]
    document.getElementById("hi").src=x
}
```

```html
        <button onclick="go()">start</button>
        <img id="hi"></img>
```